How to stop a DPST (NC) Relay from auto-resetting?
I have designed a thermal protection circuit, where once a thermistor temperature reading exceeds 40 °C (104 °F), a LM393 comparator is triggered to feed a low DC signal to a NPN transistor base pin, which in turn trips a DPST relay (normally closed) so the relay switch is now open.
The DPST relay is breaking two live wires to a separate unit, which I have thermistors attached to, if the temperature is too high.
How can I modify my circuit to prevent this relay from automatically resetting when the temperature reduces to normal operating range?


Please show a schematic, you can edit your question and draw one with the tool

I have added a schematic now.

Your circuit won't work without a pullup on the (open-collector) comparator output.
One possibility is to add another transistor and (optionally) a resistor to add positive feedback to the circuit. I've changed the relay driver to a MOSFET. If you use BJTs the circuit will be similar but with two base resistors, and the reset temperature won't be as easy to calculate.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
By picking R4 judiciously you can have the circuit self-reset at a lower temperature (based on the value of RT||R4). Without that, you'll need a switch or something to reset the circuit and it might power up in an undesirable state, so that also should be dealt with appropriately.

@ Spehro 'speff' Pefhany : according comparator datasheet, "If IN- is lower than IN+ and the offset voltage, the output is high impedance and the output transistor is not conducting"; in this condition, relays, M2 and M3 will be switched on, IN+ will be pulled down, and output will  change and sink current (oscilation).  I think this feed back should pull down IN-.

@Bravale Yes, you're right.  But the relay logic is reversed- assuming NTC thermistors. The transistor + resistor will make the thermistors read higher than actual temperature so it's what we want, but the relay output logic should be reversed (inputs swapped from OP's schematic). And Circuitlab is not not letting me edit.

Thank you for that guidance. From reading online, I was considering using a SR Flip-Flop (NAND) in the circuit instead of a NPN Transistor. When temperature exceeds the threshold, the comparator output goes high, setting the flip flop and energizing the relay. The relay remains energized until a manual reset switch is pressed, resetting the flip flop and de-energizing the relay. But I haven't put this circuit down on Circuitmaker etc yet, need to review whether the logic works for this project or not.
